# Как сделать перевод слов с помощью json?

Tags: python, json

Хочу реализовать через проверку, перевод слова. Материалов я не нашёл в интернете, либо плохо "гуглил".

Есть json, где хранятся слова с переводом:

```
{
    "RunestoneRare":"Редкий рунный камень",
    "EssenceRare":"Редкую эссенцию",
    "DustRare":"Редкую пыль"
}
```

А также, есть файл, откуда берётся название предмета через регулярное выражение, где идёт постоянная проверка на строчку: `(REWARD) -> Player win Item:25`. Предметов много, в json привёл пару примеров.

---

Пример строчки: `(REWARD) -> Player win RunestoneRare:1`, как сделать так, чтобы `RunestoneRare` при выводе переименовался в слово из `json`-файла.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть метод `словарь.get(ключ, значение_по_умолчанию_при_отсутствии_ключа)`. Получив необходимую подстроку, её и можно использовать в виде ключа словаря.

```
import re

ru = {
    "RunestoneRare": "Редкий рунный камень",
    "EssenceRare": "Редкую эссенцию",
    "DustRare": "Редкую пыль"
}

def replacer(match_obj):
    full_match = match_obj.group(0) # "RunestoneRare", совпадение целиком.

    return ru.get(full_match, full_match)


txt = '(REWARD) -> Player win RunestoneRare:1'

print( re.sub(r'(?<=win\s)[^:]+', replacer, txt) )
# (REWARD) -> Player win Редкий рунный камень:1
```

`r'(?<=win\s)[^:]+'`: «Positive lookbehind» `(?<=)` не входит в объект совпадения, но гарантирует, что все совпавшие подстроки будут находиться после `win\s` (`\s` - **s**pace, пробельный символ).

`[^:]+` — «Не» `[^:]` двоеточие, `+` один или много раз подряд.

Comment: А можно ли вместо `(?<=win\s)[^:]+`, вписать переменную?

Comment: @hoojpop можно, `regex = r'ваше_выражение'` ... `re.sub(regex, replacer, txt)` точнее, перед строкой не обязательно должна быть буква `r`, это всего лишь «row string», в котором можно свободно использовать символы «\». Это может быть и обычная строка. Но придется использовать двойные «\\» при необходимости